# Does Kml support a link to video files?

Tags: kml, kmz

I am creating a KMZ file containing one KML file and other resource folder which contains a video and an image.
I know kml supports html inside description tag. So I am trying to show images and videos through that html code.
Showing an Image is fine. It is showing perfectly, but I am really interested in playing video files when I click on marker
The tool I am using to plot kmz file is [here](http://kmlviewer.nsspot.net).

Answer (score 0):

KML supports HTML in the description element of the placemark which is displayed in a popup. The HTML can contain an `iframe` element with URL to a video that can be played using the Adobe Flash player.

In Google Earth release 4.2 and higher, video is supported.

See [Adobe Flash in Google Earth](https://www.gearthblog.com/blog/archives/2015/06/adobe-flash-google-earth.html) and this [KML example](https://www.gearthblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/UrtheCast-sample-videos.kml).

Note that embedded video via HTML EMBED tag was supported in Google Earth but no longer supported as of Google Earth 7.x. (See [Example](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#samplevideo)).